# Computing the checksum of an array of bytes in 68HC11 assembly language

Tags: assembly, 68hc11

The checksum is computed as the sum without carry of each byte of the array and is put in the register B. The size of the array is in register A and the array is in memory starting at the address in register X.

So far I got this program:

```
      ORG  $C000

      LDAA #N
      LDAB #$00
LOOP  DECA

      ADDB 0,X
      INX
      CMPA #0
      BNE  LOOP
END
```

I think that would do the job but I'm new with assembly and the 68HC11. Can you tell if you see something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know that assembly, but aren't you forgetting to decrement A? Oh, never mind, you have DECA, it's not part of LOOP... :)

Comment: ok so DECA shouldn't be part of the loop? and it is an assignment.

Comment: Your code would be more efficient if you removed the first DECA, and replaced the CMPA #0 with DECA.  Of course, your code as written won't handle a zero-length array, which happens in practice.  I agree with @hyde; while this computes a checksum, you should use a stronger scheme (as he suggested) in practice.  Those are are lot harder to code.

Comment: thanks for your comment very helpful! If you want post it as an answer and I'll accepted. And how do I make the code to handle zero-length array?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to handle zero-length array (will return B=0):

```
      LDAB #$00
      LDAA #N
      BEQ END
LOOP  ADDB 0,X
      INX
      DECA
      BNE  LOOP
END
```